# Changing button style in the whole application

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-button, android-styles

I'm trying to change all the TextColor of my buttons in my app to white and also trying to make it bold. But that isn't happening, I'm overwriting `the android:Widget.Button`
I'm developing for Jelly Bean 4.1.2
What am I doing wrong?

**Theme definition in manifest**

```
android:theme="@style/spui" >
```

**The theme where I like to**

```
<style name="spui" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Buttonspui</item>
</style>
```

**The style for the button itself**

```
  <style name="Buttonspui" parent="android:Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
      <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
```

**The button**

```
 <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:text="@string/edit"
     android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
     style="@style/Buttonspui"/>
```

Comment: Try to apply that style to every Button. that will work.

Comment: if you are applying this theme in the application, make sure you are not applying another for the activity or the button itself.

Comment: The button itself doesn't have another style

Comment: And normally I shouldn't define a style for the button because I'm overwriting `android:Widget.Button` that I defined as the parent of the style

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For styling your `Button` you can use this:

Go to the `drawable` folder and make an XML (e.g. `button.xml`) file called "style" which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

    <item>
         <shape>
             <gradient android:startColor="#449def" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:angle="270" />
             <stroke   android:width="1px"          android:color="#000000" />  
                <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>       
              <padding  android:left="10dp"  android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
         </shape>  
   </item> 

</selector>
```

This is my code, you can make the necessary changes you want

Now call it in your layout XML (`mainactivity.xml`) like this

```
android:background="@drawable/button.xml"
```

Now to change the font color and style you can use the following which comes as part of the `styles.xml` in the values folder

```
<style name="buttonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Now call this in the layout XML (`mainactivity.xml`) like this

```
  style="@style/buttonStyle"
```

The final code is:

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
 android:text="@string/edit"
 android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
 android:background="@drawable/button.xml"
 style="@style/buttonStyle"
/>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is the right answer. But still can't believe Google hasn't provide a more consistent way to make a global theme for the button. Semantically this is wrong. We have to specify a background and style manually instead of letting us modify the default theme.

Comment: I've tried this, everything works except textColor. It just doesn't inherit the white color but displays black. All the others are inherited correctly from the style and background. If I set the same property explicitly on button instance, it works. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

This will change the default button style for the entire app, include alert dialog button. Adjust the style based on yours.

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Your base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Other styles -->
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonText</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

res/drawable/selector_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

res/drawable/button_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/buttonSelected"/>
</shape>
```

res/drawable/button_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/buttonUnselected"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: how to apply in button?

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan You could use `style="@style/selector_button"` in your XML or `Button(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.selector_button))` if you are creating your button programmatically.