# Change hover image button without selector on android

Tags: android, android-selector

I have many buttons for my view. Each button has different image resource. 
I want to change the click and hover effect for each button like this:

**Button 1**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn1_selector"
        android:text="name"
         />
```

**btn1_selector**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_btn" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_btn" android:state_focused="true">/item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn1"></item>

 </selector>
```

**Button 2**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn2_selector"
        android:text="name"
         />
```

**btn2_selector**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_btn" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_btn" android:state_focused="true">/item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn2"></item>

 </selector>

// etc...
```

The problem is that I have to create many selectors for all buttons. But I just need to change the hover state for all of them with 1 image `hover_btn.png`.
 Is there any way to have a hover state by default **without creating all selectors for all buttons**?

Comment: When the background of your button is always the same, why do you duplicate the button selectors?

Comment: @DenisLoh just the hover state image of buttons are same. The default background of each button is different. See my updated question

Comment: Maybe from styles, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192104/changing-button-style-in-the-whole-application