# How to change style of all the buttons in android studio?

Tags: android

Style.xml File(AppTheme is the theme of my app and it is inheriting materiallightdarkactionbar theme)

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/holo_orange_light</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/newbuttonstyle</item>
</style>
<style name="newbuttonstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#acd9e6</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I am designing a calculator and this is the keypad for it.....rather than individually setting background tint for all the buttons I want to change the style of all my buttons in one go using style.xml....can i do so?

[image: img]

In this I am using buttonStyle and still it is not working

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/newbuttonstyle</item>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a style to all buttons of an Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application)

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192104/changing-button-style-in-the-whole-application

Comment: You all are saying that i have to explicitly mention the style in the button itself then what is the use of this?                                                                                                       <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/newbuttonstyle</item>

Answer (score 2):

in your XML file

```
<Button
style="@style/MyButtonStyle" 
android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="my button"/>
```

in style.xml file add this code.

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

change Style items as per your requirements.

Comment: isn't there i way to define the style for all button in one go??

Comment: its last and best way for give style for all buttons.

Comment: just you have to put style="@style/MyButtonStyle"  in all buttons.. thats it

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="newbuttonstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#acd9e6</item>
</style>
```

I am using above code in my application and its working fine.i think set background instead of backgroundTint.
 May be its working .

check this link:
[ReferenceLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080463/1223291)

and its some issue in tintbackground in lolipop.so you have to check in below lolipop.

Comment: This only works when I define  style="@style/newbuttonstyle" for each button....but what is the use of <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/newbuttonstyle</item> in AppTheme style

Comment: what is your compilesdk version?

Comment: 24 is my compile sdk version

Comment: plz change to 21 and check its working or not.if its working then we will find solution for version 24 issue

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this question, hope it will be work for you and clear your style portion: 
   [Android Material Design Button Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles)